# Resizing the bootstrap container width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The bootstrap `.conatiner` div has a style, what is it below:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .container {
        width: 1170px!important;
    }
}
```

Can i overwrite this `1170px` width to `80%`, or **higher**? Only in that media query.

Comment: Ofc, you can overwrite `1170px` to `80%` but keep it in mind, `.container` gonna be expand in `80%` of its parent (that maybe is the width of window browser) so simple answer to your question is: Yes you can. To answer to your comment about worrying about display error: Maybe, we don't know what elements are in your page that depends on exact `1170px` width.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite it by inline CSS style or taking advantage of priority because downer codes overwrite upper codes:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .container {
        width: 1170px!important;
    }

    .container {
        width: 80% !important;
    }
}
```

**Please note**: The downer code must have `!important` afterward.

Comment: And if i overwrite it, it will not cause any display errors on  the page?

Comment: @max777, the browsers are kind and merciful, so no.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" width="80%">Contaier body</div>
```

or you can go to your css file and change the width

```
.container{
    width:80%;
}
```